# Want Chrome browser to ask for certificate each time

Tags: google-chrome

I have a site I visited where I need to use different certificates for different tasks. I visited the site once and selected a certificate. Now Chrome just assumes that certificate.

I want Chrome to ask me which certificate to use every time I visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove a certificate in Chrome via
*Settings > Advanced > Manage certificates*.

A dialog will be displayed with all the stored certificates, where you
can delete the certificate for that by selecting it and clicking the
*Remove* button.
You may also use the buttons of "Export..." and "Import..." to save
and restore certificates.

If you don't want future certificates to be remembered,
access this website using an Incognito browsing window.

Another mechanism you may use is having multiple
[profiles](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en),
as the certificates are local to the profile.

Comment: I don't want to remove any certificates. I will want to select it again at at later date.

Comment: Added above some more options.

Comment: yeah, accessing in incognito mode accomplishes what i want. thanks.