# Force Chrome to show certificate selection dialog in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, client-certificate

Some sites (e.g,
https://www.sede.fnmt.gob.es/certificados/persona-fisica/verificar-estado/solicitar-verificacion) require the selection of a local certificate. Chrome, once you select one of the certificates, "saves" the option and, when you re-enter the page, uses the last certificate selected.

I would like to reset the selection and have Chrome ask again when entering the page.

In Firefox there is an option in Settings / Privacy and Security/ View Certificates / Certificates decissions, but I can't find anything similar in Chrome. Nor have I found any configuration file or database from which it can be changed.

I know I can use profiles, browse incognito and delete and re-import certificates in the browser ([Want Chrome browser to ask for certificate each time](https://superuser.com/questions/1466232/want-chrome-browser-to-ask-for-certificate-each-time)) but I would find it much more practical to do it by modifying some option or file.

Do you know if there is a way to do this?

I'm working with Ubuntu 20.04 and Chrome 114.0.5735.198 (64 bit).